# How to auto scroll display:table when overflow?

Tags: css, overflow, css-tables

How to display scroll bar when overflow if `display:table` ?

Sample code:

https://jsfiddle.net/mvnvnk5z/

html:

```
<div class="chatpanel">
<div id="chatcontent">
    <p class="userchat">hello</p>
     <p class="userchat">hello2</p>
     <p class="userchat">hello3</p>
     <p class="userchat">hello4</p>
     <p class="userchat">hello5</p>
     <p class="userchat">hello6</p>
     <p class="userchat">hello7</p>
     <p class="userchat">hello8</p>

    </div>    
</div>
```

css:

```
.chatpanel{
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;

}
#chatcontent {
    display:table-cell;

}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change  `overflow-y:auto;` to  `overflow-y:scroll;` if you're looking forward to have scroll on overflowed content in **y-axis**, you can follow the same pattern for **x-axis**, here's the sample code; 
[Scroll](https://jsfiddle.net/mvnvnk5z/2/)

Comment: as you're using a table display, go with "line-height" syntax, and specify a desired height.

Comment: It's ok, i found the solution by adding wrapper div above tables. code : https://jsfiddle.net/mvnvnk5z/5/

Answer (score 0):

Use this code Check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mvnvnk5z/8/)

```
 <div class="chatpanel">
      <div id="chatcontent" style="overflow-y:auto;height:100px;">
                <p class="userchat">hello</p>
                <p class="userchat">hello2</p>
                <p class="userchat">hello3</p>
                <p class="userchat">hello4</p>
                <p class="userchat">hello5</p>
                <p class="userchat">hello6</p>
                <p class="userchat">hello7</p>
                <p class="userchat">hello8</p>

       </div>    
 </div>
```

> Enjoy...!